# dd selection of partitions to usb

Tags: filesystems

My Proxmox installation on /dev/sda consists of three partitions:

1. /dev/sda1 (1007K) BIOS Boot
2. /dev/sda2 (512M)  EFI
3. /dev/sda3 (409G) /usr (ZFS partition)

I want to copy sda1 and sda2 over to a usb key (4G). Obviously sda3 will not fit on the usb key.

Without success I tried:
`dd if=/dev/sda1 if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/sdb bs=1M;sync`

What is the right command to copy a selection of filesystems to another drive as described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write multiple sources like this with `dd` because `dd` doesn't write "archive" information; there would be no way of restoring the files!

A simple solution would be to create a file system, mount it, and copy the files there.

For example (this may not work for you and may need tuning)

```
# mke2fs -j /dev/sdb
# mount /dev/sdb /mnt
# dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/mnt/sda1.image
# dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/mnt/sda2.image
# ls /mnt
sda1.image    sda2.image
# umount /mnt
```